# Angular radio buttons - undefined value on check

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have radiobuttons in Angular 1 like this http://jsfiddle.net/md3coyzn/1/ and I need to change value to true / false when radio button is clicked, but I am still getting undefined value, and dont know why

```
$scope.radioContent = [
    {txt: 'One', checked: true},
    {txt: 'Two', checked: false}
];


<div ng-repeat="radio in radioContent">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="radio.checked">{{radio.txt}} ---> {{radio.checked}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as *ng-repeat* create its own scope. so you have to access by using $parent

#### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="radio in radioContent track by $index">
        <input type="radio" name="group[$index]" ng-model="$parent.selectedRadio" ng-change="$parent.radioChecked()" ng-value="radio" >{{radio.txt}}      
    </div>
```

#### JS

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedRadio;
    $scope.radioContent = [
        {txt: 'One', checked: true},
        {txt: 'Two', checked: false}
    ];

    $scope.radioChecked = function () {
        console.log('selectedRadio', $scope.selectedRadio);
        $scope.selectedRadio.checked = !$scope.selectedRadio.checked
    }
}]);
```

please check the [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/md3coyzn/4/)

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

An `ng-click` method to toggle the value of the radio buttons.

Note that `value` attribute of the button conflicts with the `ng-model` attribute so had to remove the later one.

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])

.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
console.clear();
    $scope.radioContent = [
        {txt: 'One', checked: true},
        {txt: 'Two', checked: false}
    ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="radio in radioContent">
        <input type="radio" name="group" value="{{radio.checked}}" ng-click="radio.checked = !radio.checked">{{radio.txt}} ---> {{radio.checked}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is also not works correctly https://snag.gy/bzLPo6.jpg

Comment: What's not working correct? When you click on radio button, value changes from true to false or false to true.